# Not using force unwrapping in guard statement when throwing an ErrorType in Swift

Tags: swift

I want to remove force unwrap (`fetchRequestError!`) from this code. I know that It must not make problems because when `mainQueuePosts` is nil `fetchRequestError` has value. But I want to make it better. And I don't want the retu

```
func fetchMainQueuePost(predicate predicate: NSPredicate? = nil,
                                      sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor]? = nil) throws -> [SeenPosts] {

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "SeenPosts")
        let mainQueueContext = coreDataStack.mainQueueContext
        var mainQueuePosts: [SeenPosts]?
        var fetchRequestError: ErrorType?
        mainQueueContext.performBlockAndWait() {
            do {
                mainQueuePosts = try mainQueueContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as? [SeenPosts]
            } catch let error {
                fetchRequestError = error
            }
        }

        guard let posts = mainQueuePosts else {
            throw fetchRequestError!
        }

        return posts
    }
```

My solution, which is not good is:

```
 guard let posts = mainQueuePosts else {
    if let err = fetchRequestError {
       throw err
    }
    fatalError()
 }
```

`fatalError()` is never executed. but I think its not a good idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to `throw` an error in a method which `throws` itself is to hand over the error to the caller by removing the `do - catch` block.

As a standard `fetch` is synchronous anyway you don't need `performBlockAndWait()` and you can safely forced downcast to `[SeenPosts]` because the fetch request is distinct.

If the fetch succeeds the array will be returned, in case of an error the error will be thrown.

```
func fetchMainQueuePost(predicate predicate: NSPredicate? = nil,
                        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor]? = nil) throws -> [SeenPosts] {

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "SeenPosts")
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors
    return try coreDataStack.mainQueueContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [SeenPosts]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to use "as!" too.

Comment: As already mentioned `as!` is 100% safe in this case. It will never crash

Comment: You can avoid the `as!` by declaring your fetch request as `NSFetchRequest<SeenPosts>` Swift generics to the rescue!

Comment: @dpassage Thanks. I changed it to:          let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<SeenPosts> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "SeenPosts")
  but it has an error: cannot specialize non-generic type nsfetchrequest

Comment: @dpassage The code is Swift 2 code. I highly recommend to update to Swift 3. Then you can take advantage of the generic fetch request.